# Coefficient estimated with a binary predictor $\in \{0,1\}$, but making predictions with values between $0$ and $1$ - is this OK?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, interpolation

Let's say I have a variable $x_d$ that, in the estimation data, is a simple indicator ($x_d \in \left\{0,1\right\}$).  I estimate a coefficient for it, $\beta_d$, along with several other coefficients for variables that could be continuous, more dummies, etc.

Now someone wants to use these coefficients in a forecast. For their input data, they would like to treat $x_d$ not as an indicator, but rather as a continuous variable. That is, while the estimation data represented this quantity as an either/or, the forecast data represents it more as a matter of degree.  In this forecast data, I would hope that my colleague would constrain the value of $x_d$ between 0 and 1, but we have not yet discussed that.

#### Edit

$x_d$ describes whether a loan came from a very specific lender.  So in reality, the value really is only 0 or 1.  In the forecast, my colleague wants to treat that variable as a continuous measure of similarity to that lender, i.e. how much like that lender is a loan’s source, with 0 meaning not at all, and 1 meaning the same lender.  Is it a bad thing to alter the meaning in that way?  I’m especially concerned about how it affects the meanings of the other coefficients, which were estimated alongside an indicator and are now being used alongside a continuous variable.

Are there any issues when a coefficient is estimated with an indicator/dummy, but then used in a forecast with a continuous variable?

Comment: Yes I think you should be concerned about this. Why are you using an estimated coefficient for another variable on a new variable?

Comment: @whuber:  thanks for edit, that definitely should be part of the original question.

Comment: after our discussion under Michael's answer, the true nature of the question was clarified for me and I've modified the title accordingly - I hope the change I've made was OK. If not, please modify it appropriately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After clarification in a comment discussion, it appears that the question is about a situation where there is a linear model relating a continuous response variable $Y_i$ and a binary predictor $X_i \in \{0,1\}$, and the OP wants to know whether or not it is defensible to interpolate by plugging in values for $X_i$ that are $\in (0,1)$ and assuming everything is "OK". That answer is that this is only defensible **if you assume linearity of $E(Y_i | X_i)$ over that interval**.

To see why this is true, consider fitting these data with a simple regression model:

$$ Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + \varepsilon_i $$

where $\varepsilon_i$ is a mean $0$ error term. Under this model, $E(Y_i | X_i = 1) = \beta_0 + \beta_1$ and $E(Y_i | X_i = 0) = \beta_0$. When you only use data such that each $X_i \in \{0,1\}$ to fit this model, the coefficient estimates will be exactly

$$ \hat \beta_0 = \overline{Y_0}$$

and

$$ \hat \beta_1 = \overline{Y_1} - \overline{Y_0}$$

where $\overline{Y_0}$ is the sample mean of the $Y_i$'s when $X_i = 0$ and $\overline{Y_1}$ is the sample mean of the $Y_i$'s when $X_i = 1$. Therefore, the estimated mean for any intermediate value of $X_i$, call it $x$, is

$$ \overline{Y_0} + (\overline{Y_1} - \overline{Y_0})x = \overline{Y_0}(1-x) + \overline{Y_1}x$$

That is, **a function which linearly goes from $\overline{Y_0}$ to $\overline{Y_1}$ as $x$ moves from $0$ to $1$**. If the true relationship is not this way, then the predictions made will be very wrong.

For example, suppose the true relationship was a step function:

$$E(Y_i | X_i) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \mathcal{I}(X_i \geq 1/2) $$

where $\mathcal{I}(X_i \geq 1/2) = 1$ if $X_i \geq 1/2$ and 0 otherwise. This would be compatible with the linear model specified if all you observe are $X_i = 0,1$ but once you start to interpolate that linear relationship, you will get very wrong predictions. At $X_i = 1/2$, the true mean is $\beta_0 + \beta_1$ but the linear model's estimate would be $\beta_0 + \beta_1/2$ (Yikes!). Other examples can be given where the linear model is correct for the binary data, but makes this disagreement arbitrarily large once you interpolate.

Answer (score 2):

Of course I agree with Macro here.  These are two entirely different models.  The coefficient for an indicator variable would bear no relation to what the coefficient should have been had you fit the model with a continuous variable.  If you have data on the continuous variable you would be better off fitting the model to that.  By dichotomizing the variable you throw out information in your data.

Comment: +1. While I don't entirely agree that "The coefficient for an indicator variable would bear no relation to what the coefficient should have been had you fit the model with a continuous variable" - there will be _some_ relation - but I think you could come up with examples where the coefficient on the raw variable and the coefficient on the discretized version are arbitrarily different to any pre-specified degree, which is, I think, what you meant.

Comment: @Macro I meant that they need not be very similar and it could be very bad to use one in place of the other going either way.  But particularly from the coefficient for the indicator variable to be used with the continuous one.

Comment: Agreed. The only time the two will agree is when the true effect of the continuous variable is a step function, which wouldn't be well approximated by a linear model, so, in that case, you might as well just use the discrete variable for prediction anyways.

Comment: I think this reply may be a little too strong and perhaps loses a chance to focus on a key issue, which is model mis-specification. Take the toy example of regressing $y$ only on $x$ with $x$ ranging in $[0,1]$. In some ways it is *optimal* to design the data collection so half the $x$'s equal $0$ and the other half equal $1$: this minimizes the S.E. of the slope. We don't do this in practice because we need other values of $x$ to check possible non-linearity (model mis-specification). Absent such nonlinearity, the estimated parameters will be *excellent* for *all* $x$.

Comment: @whuber Whise reply are you referring to?  Mine or Macros?  I am not sure why in your toy example the choice of equal numbers at only the extremes minimizes the SE of the slope. Since the extremes are high leverage points the slope would be very sensitive to outliers in the y values. I do appreciate your point about looking at intermediate value to be able to detect nonlinearities.

Comment: (Michael, this comment thread pertains to just one *reply*: yours. Comments are not replies.) I was thinking of [D-optimal designs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_design). The design I described is D-optimal (for one I.V.): it's a minimum-volume bounding ellipse. The extremes will not have high leverage when they are the only two values of $x$ and they are equally frequent in the dataset. The sensitivity to outliers is an interesting point: that goes hand-in-hand with the optimality and provides another reason to be cautious when fitting a model with only two distinct values of $x$.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, I'm guessing whuber is referring to the fact that, in linear regression with normal errors, the standard error is inversely related to the variance in the predictor, which is maximized when half are 0 and half are 1, in that example

Comment: @Macro.  I understand that.  Similarly central composite designs are optimal for certain multifactor ANOVAs.

Comment: @whuber it may be the jargon he to refer strictly to answers to the question as reply.  But in general reply just means an answer to a question.  Questions are posed in comments as well as in formal answers and so I was thinking that my discussion with Macro amounted to a give and take that included replies in the dictionary sense of the word.

Comment: @all: I should have described $x_d$ some more. In reality, $x_d$ isn't continuous:  it really is either 0 or 1.  It describes whether or not a loan came from a very specific lender. In the forecast, my colleague wants to treat that variable as a continuous measure of similarity to that lender, i.e. how much like that lender is a loan’s source, with $0$ meaning not at all, and $1$ meaning the same lender. I have lots of concerns, including how this affects the meanings of the other coefficients, which were estimated alongside an indicator, but are now being used alongside a continuous variable.

Comment: @sparc_spread, if the variable takes on only the values $0$ and $1$, using it as an indicator or a continuous variable will give the same coefficient estimates.

Comment: @Macro: that's certainly true. I guess what I mean to say is, we estimated those coefficients in a world where something either was or was not true.  In the forecast, we're now saying that that thing could be just partially true.  It almost feels like the forecaster is saying, "remember all the zeros in the estimation data? Well, they actually should have been somewhere in the interval $[0,1)$."  Does this alter the meaning of the other coefficients?  Is it a misuse of the model?

Comment: I think it would be misuse of the model if you were to plug in values for $x$ that were not $0$ or $1$ and would require an explicit assumption of linearity over that interval.

Comment: @Macro: you make a strong case here that this is a misuse of the model, for I believe that an assumption of linearity for the continuous version of $x_d$ would be highly subjective indeed. Could you explain a bit why we would need to assume linearity here? Thanks.

Comment: @sparc_spread - sure. Please see my answer below.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help here!  This thread plus the other one have really given me the insight needed to debate this issue intelligently with my teammates.